# Entity Framework sorting nested collection

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

How would I sort (`orderby`) property of a nested collection (collection within a collection)

```
if (query.Sort.ProjectA == SortOperation.Desc)
{
    entities = entities
               .OrderByDescending(r => r.ProjectCollection.Select(p => p.JobNumber));
}
else
{
    entities = entities.OrderBy(r => r.ProjectCollection.Select(p =>p.JobNumber));
}
```

I get the following error for the code above

> DbSortClause expressions must have a type that is order comparable.
>   Parameter name: key

Comment: Are you trying to sort the parent collection or each child collection?

Comment: sort by a property inside of the inner collection

Comment: Sort the parent collection by a property on the inner collection?

Answer (score 2):

Reverse your use of `Select` and `OrderBy`.  Don't order by a selected collection, select out an ordered collection:

```
var query = entities.Select(r => r.ProjectACollection.OrderBy(p => p.JobNumber));
```

If you want other fields as well, select out a new entity or some other type with all of the other fields that you want included as well.

Comment: I get the following then Error 14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<Toolbox.EntityModel.Entities.ProjectA>>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<Toolbox.EntityModel.Entities.EodRecord>'.

Comment: @eugenekgn Right, the type is different in this example, so you either need to store it in a new variable or project out a new instance of the same type, which means copying all of the properties in that entity.

Comment: ProjectACollection is collection inside a main collection

Comment: @eugenekgn Yes, it is.